# how to deal with object disappearance particle filter object tracking

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wonder if anyone is working in acoustic tracking. I use particle filter for sound source tracking and it works well for my project. However, in the situation when sound source disappear and reappear, particle filter wont work. Is there a way to detect object disappearance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228758/how-to-deal-with-object-disappearance-particle-filter-object-tracking/) by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 150 on 2016-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try to predict the lost data and recover the tracks after the data becomes available.

---

Originally posted by [ja_ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/26244/ja_ros/) with karma: 31 on 2016-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on 2016-03-13**:
The problem is that currently i track the loudest sound source. If the sound source is not present, other ambient sound is gonna be in place which is false (particle filter will keep tracking these false sound sources). therefore, I need some kind of feature to separate interest source and the other

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on 2016-03-13**:
Also, how can i recover the particle filter, should i re distribute the particles all over place, or move the existing particles to the highest probability position